# Running a Spring MVC application with Jetty gives "class path resource does not exist"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jetty

I'm new to Spring and I encountered a small problem: the web application runs perfectly when using Tomcat but has problem when running it with Jetty.

I run the following commands:

```
mvn package
java -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar target/*.war
```

The error I get is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring-config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Part of my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        ...
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.4.5.v20110725</version>
                                    <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Part of my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
    ...
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    ...
</web-app>
```

Part of my /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    ...
    <import resource="classpath:spring-config.xml" />
</beans>
```

The relevant directories structure:

```
- src
--main
---java
----spring-config.xml
---webapp
----WEB-INF
-----applicationContext.xml
-----web.xml
-pom.xml
```

Seems to be a problem with the classpath definition but I don't know how to solve the problem. I already tried to specify the classpath with `java -cp "..." ...` or `java -Djetty.class.path="..." ...`

Any help is very appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spring-config.xml` file should be in `src/main/resources`. XML files in the Java source directory won't be included on the classpath.

This is automatic if you use the jetty plugin and run with `mvn jetty:run` (or `jetty:run-war`).

Comment: Thank you, Dave. I have moved the spring-config.xml file to src/main/resources as you said but now I don't know how to reference it in applicationContext.xml (<import resource="???" />). Furthermore, looking at some SpringSource official example they always put this kind of XML in the classpath, as I've done. Is there any way to tell Jetty to look at the XML files in the classpath as well? Thanks

Comment: @satoshi Jetty is not part of Spring config resolution. Web config files, like `web.xml`, should *not* be on the classpath--it must be located in `WEB-INF`.

Comment: But if I put my spring-config.xml in the WEB-INF directory, how can I reference it from the unit/system test environnment? Basically, I have two different Spring configuration files, one for unit testing (src/test/java/system-test-config.xml) and one for the website (src/main/webapp/applicationContext.xml, that is referenced in the web.xml as shown above). They both reference spring-config.xml so I think that I can't move it in the WEB-INF directory, right? Thanks

Comment: @satoshi I said that *web* config files, like container configs, should go in WEB-INF, and Spring config files should go on the classpath.

Comment: But if I put it in the classpath it gives me errors, that's why I asked the original question...

Comment: @satoshi ... Your web.xml hard-codes the Spring config to WEB-INF instead of putting it on the classpath. Your tests should create its own set of config locations, or you should use a context config locater that interrogates a system property or other way of indicating that different config file(s) should be loaded. Your original question was why the spring-config.xml file wasn't being loaded, which I answered.

Comment: Thank you, Dave. I've solved the problem following your suggestions!

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  mvn:run-war works fine, mvn:run-jetty complains that it cannot find the spring-context.xml in the classpath.  In the exploded war, I do see the context file in classes/META-INF/spring-context.xml

Answer (score 1):

Your CLASSPATH doesn't include the Spring context.

I'd advise you to package your app into a WAR and deploy that to Jetty.  WEB-INF/classes is always in the CLASSPATH, so if you copy your Spring context XML to that directory the class loader will find them.

Do you need a `ContextLoaderListener` in your web.xml?

I see applicationContext.xml mentioned in your web.xml, but not spring-config.xml.  That's the one the class loader is complaining about.

Comment: It's in `applicationContext.xml`, but since it's not in the resources directory, it will be ignored and not be put on the classpath during the build process.